# Is there a way to detect when loading tiles has failed?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Is there a way to detect when the tile server cannot be contacted with OpenLayers?  I want to display a "Tile server cannot be found" failure message instead of just those ugly "image not found" red X tiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as an FYI to anyone who needs to do this, I solved this with the following code (placed BEFORE I created my map, layers, etc.):

```
OpenLayers.Util.onImageLoadError = function () {
    this.src = "images/noTile.png";
}
```

where images/noTile.png was the image I used as the "Tile not found" image.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenLayers.Util.onImageLoadError does not seem to be available anymore. They seem to have replaced it by the a css styling of missing tiles using the .olImageLoadError selector. Any alternatives to detect the failure of one or more tiles?

Comment: Actually, you can search for elements with the olImageLoadError class in the page to detect missing tiles. This solved my problem at least.